# Docusign rest api composite template error

Tags: json, httprequest, docusignapi

I've made composite templates and had them working before, but I'm suddenly getting an error and have no idea why this is causing an issue. Here's my request:

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/356019/envelopes HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.docusign.net
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>test@gmail.com</Username><Password>*****</Password><IntegratorKey>****</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MY_BOUNDARY
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 807319
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive


--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
                "emailSubject": "Please Docusign this",
                                   "emailBlurb": "This is a test... Also sign this form",
                                   "enableWetSign": "true",
                                   "status": "sent",
                "compositeTemplates": [
                    {
                        "inlineTemplates": [
                            {
                                "sequence": "1",
                                "recipients": {
                                    "signers": [
                                        {
                                            "email": "test@gmail.com",
                                            "name": "test",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }],
                        "document":
                            {
                                "documentId": "1",
                                "name": "test0",
                                "fileExtension": "pdf"
                            }
                        }
                ]
            }
--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test0.pdf"; documentid="1"

<pdf bytes here>

--MY_BOUNDARY--
```

I have this working with server templates, but it seems like anything that requires the document object gives me a bad request. The request I'm getting is:

Request Error: BadRequestDocuSign Error: {
  "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
  "message": "the document is corrupt, rebuilding failed"
}

I've read the pdf bytes in another program and have successfully created a pdf from it, so I'm not sure what could be causing this issue. Does anybody know what the problem may be? Thank you  for your time.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your Request structure/contents, and I am able to create an envelope with an identically structured request -- so it's likely not an issue with the DocuSign service.  Perhaps try using another (different) PDF, to determine if DocuSign's just having trouble reading "test0.pdf" ?

Comment: That does seem to be the issue. I've used another pdf and it works fine. I just find it odd that I can create and open that test0.pdf from the bytes, but I can't create it in an envelope. I've used a random pdf document I have on my computer and it worked correctly. I'll probably have to look into it a little more. Thank you for helping me narrow it down.

Comment: In troubleshooting the issues for that particular PDF, you might want to examine the properties of the file -- i.e., if it's encrypted or protected or something like that, then DocuSign might be having issues reading it for that reason. Also, anytime you think you might be having file issues like this via API, it's often helpful to try manually uploading the same file to a DocuSign Envelope via the DocuSign UI -- if the file's corrupt or something like that, then it won't upload via the console either, and then you at least know it's an issue with the file and not an API issue.